# Google Ads not showing up in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, ads

I'm having an odd issue, Google Ads (DFP) aren't showing up for IE8 (not testing for IE below 8).

I'm using the following code (jQuery in use).

```
/*-- Advertizing --*/
var googletag = googletag || {};
googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
(function(){
    var script = $('<{0}></{0}>'.format('script'));
    script.attr('type','text/javascript');
    script.attr('async','async');
    script.attr('src',document.location.protocol + '//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js');
    $('head').eq(0).prepend(script);

    googletag.cmd.push(function() {
        googletag.defineSlot('/1016203/PG_194x662_Async', [194, 662], 'div-gpt-ad-1320434986666-0').addService(googletag.pubads());
        googletag.defineSlot('/1016203/PG_530x99_Async', [530, 99], 'div-gpt-ad-1320435053303-0').addService(googletag.pubads());
        googletag.defineSlot('/1016203/PG_530x50_Async', [530, 50], 'div-gpt-ad-1320435026691-0').addService(googletag.pubads());
        googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
        googletag.enableServices();
    });
    googletag.cmd.push(function () { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1320434986666-0'); });
    googletag.cmd.push(function () { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1320435053303-0'); });
    googletag.cmd.push(function () { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1320435026691-0'); });       
}());
```

This is tested, and working correctly in IE9, Chrome, Firefox... But IE8 is the odd one out.  The site is up at [photogallery.classiccars.com](http://photogallery.classiccars.com/).  It almost looks (from the DOM tree) that one IFrame is partially loaded in IE8, but just drops out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google's code is using a `for (var x in array)`, which has issues in some browsers when Array.prototype is extended.

Why they aren't using the .length property for iteration, or checking hasOwnProperty is beyond me, but that appears to be the issue at hand.

Because [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) is included in the project, which requires [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/), I am adjusting the codebase to use the utility methods from [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) for the project.

```
//instead of an ES5-Shim extension to Array.prototype.filter (for example)
var ary = [...];

//instead of this...
var results = ary.filter(function(item){...}); //es5

//use this
var results = _.filter(ary, function(item){...}); //underscore.js
```

A note to anyone writing JavaScript, avoid using for..in unless you are explicitly checking for hasOwnProperty.  This goes for both Arrays and Objects.

```
var ary = [...];
for (var x in ary) {
    if (!ary.hasOwnProperty(x)) continue; //skip inherited properties.

    //your handling here
    ...
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little more? I have a large projects with loads of JS coming from all over the place, and my Google ads are not showing in IE8 as well. What is it that I need to change?

Comment: If you are using something that extends Array.prototype, or Object.prototype, you will have issues... I was using EcmaScript5 shimming (prototype library does similar).  Remove any such shims, and use something like lodash or underscore.